# Using Node Modules with TypeScript and Angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

I'm attempting to create a web app which allows me to send commands to an installed application via node-powershell. My tech stack is currently as follows:

- Node.js
- Angular.js
- Typescipt
- Bootstrap

I've found typings which allow me to call the node-powershell in my application via using TypeScipt, now the issue is when I do this I get errors related to child_process. After some digging around I've found out that this is because the browser cannot understand what a node.js module is.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'dir-location\node_modules\node-powershell\dist'
    resolve 'child_process' in 'dir-location\node_modules\node-powershell\dist'
      Parsed request is a module
```

To solve this (I think), I can use `browserify`to write this into javascript that the browser can understand, and then minimize it using `uglifyjs`.

This is where I'm getting stuck. I have an npm module called `node-powershell`which has gone through `browserify`, but I'm back to my original issue - typescript can't understand what this javascript file is!

I'm new to this whole front / backend development using Node / Angular so I'm pulling my hair out. If anyone could instruct on how to use a node.js module in a front-end setting using Angular and TypeScript, that would be perfect.

Thanks

Comment: The browser cannot interact (directly) with PowerShell (or other processes).  No amount of JS magic can change that.  You need to do that on your server.

Comment: Hm okay. What tech would allow me to do such a thing? I'm in need of some middle-man which can "relay" the information gathered from node.js to my front-end application.

Comment: You can use AJAX or socket.io.

Comment: So if my thoughts are correct, the stack would look like this:

Node.js <--> Socket.io <--> Angularjs

So, angular would talk to Socket.io (and vise versa) and socket.io would talk to Node.js (and vise versa), but Node.js would not interact with Angular.js (and vise versa).

Comment: Socket.io _is_ Node.js.  But you probably don't need it; you should probably use normal AJAX.

Comment: I'll need to use the node-powershell so I could use express.js to send commands and relay that info to angular via either socket.io or AJAX

Comment: *create a web app* - who is supposed to run it? Only you? *send commands to an installed application via node-powershell* - where exactly is this app installed?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if that will work as I originally thought. The server will be sitting on an AWS ES instance. The server will then prompt the user to install some software, and then I need to check if the software has been installed on the users machine, if so continue with what the app needs to do, if not report back an error.

Comment: I've actually ended up solving that problem by using a Socket.IO.Net plugin from NuGet. Allows me to send information from my desktop app to the server whom will then send that to the correct client.